# Does the Scourging Totem deal damage as soon as it lands, to people already in its area?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spheres-of-power

I am using the SoP rules and have cast a Scourging Totem. There are already creatures within the area of effect when I drop it.

[Scourging Totem](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/using-the-spheres/#War)

> This totem emits pulses of energy, damaging every enemy within your totem’s range for an amount per round equal to 1/2 your caster level (minimum: 1). This damage may be acid, electricity, cold, or fire, as chosen when the totem is created. Creatures who enter the area of effect of this totem suffer damage immediately. Creatures who remain within the area of this totem suffer damage each round at the end of your turn.

Does it count as entering the field when the field comes into effect? So is it possible to create the totem cause damage, end turn cause damage, and repeat which allows me to double the damage for the same action?

Answer (score 1):

**It would not cause damage the moment it is summoned**, only at the end of your turn, or if targets entered the area when it is not your turn.